# Unable to install URI::Escape module in Perl v5.18.2 using cpan

Tags: perl, ubuntu, cpan

I am using Perl v5.18.2 on an Ubuntu machine. Now I want to install `URI::Escape` module using `cpan`.

It throws this error message:

```
Can't exec "make": No such file or directory at
/usr/share/perl/5.18/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 2084.
```

I am running `cpan` with sudo permission.

Comment: Well, you don't have "make", just as it says. Install it. `yum install make`.

Answer (score 4):

So what's the problem?

1. `make` is installed, and isn't being found.
2. `make` isn't installed, and you need help installing it.
3. `make` isn't installed, and you don't think it should be used.

If it's the second case, you can use

```
sudo apt-get install make
```

You'll probably need the following too:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have a different flavour of make utility on your system, such as `gmake` (GNU Make), `dmake` or possibly `bmake` (BSD Make). I suggest you check to see what was used to build your perl executable by using this command line

```
perl -MConfig -E'say $Config{make}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `make`. Use your package manager to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Build-essential and GCC was missing. Thanks .
It worked :)